# How to find the range of possible numbers of vertices and edges of a convex polyhedron, given the number of faces?

Tags: general-topology, problem-solving, polyhedra

> A polyhedron has $F$ faces. Find all possible amounts of its vertices and edges.

Of course, for small values of $F$, it's possible to just list the possibilities. But how to handle the general form of that task? Just plugging the faces into Euler's formula won't be enough.

Comment: Do you allow any [abstract polyhedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_polytope) or are there geometric/topological restrictions?

Comment: You can assume that each vertex has degree $3$ or more. This leads to $3v\le 2e$, and then $e\le 3f-6$, so you have at least an upper bound on the number of possibilities. You similarly have a lower bound by assuming that the $f$ faces all have at least $3$ sides. I'm not sure whether the whole range is always achievable with flat faces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In such a question, as the cited one, "polyhedron" usually is meant to be defined as *convex*, i.e. the set of points contained within the intersection of halfspaces. There Euler's formula does apply in its easiest form, i.e. according to $V-E+F=2$. $-$ Thence in the followings we assume this setting to be given.

First we consider the medium number $S$ of edges per vertex. That one then obeys the following equation: $VS=2E$. And furthermore, by geometric restriction, we can assume $S\ge 3$. In other words we get $3\le S=2E/V$.

Solving this relation for $V$ and inserting that into Euler's equation finally provides $E\le3F-6$. Solving it instead for $E$ and inserting that into Euler's equation instead would provide $V\le2F-4$.

Next we consider the medium number $N$ of edges per face. That one then obeys the following equation: $NF=2E$. And furthermore, by geometric restriction, we can assume $N\ge 3$. In other words we get $3\le N=2E/F$.

Solving this relation for $E$ directly provides $3F/2\le E$. Solving instead for $F$ and inserting that into Euler's equation finally provides $F/2+2\le V$.

Thus, combining these results, we get:
$$\begin{array}{rcccl}
F/2+2 & \le & V & \le & 2F-4\\
3F/2 & \le & E & \le & 3F-6
\end{array}$$

As already was mentioned within a comment, these ranges however do not tell whether any according value pair of $V$ and $E$ truely would be taken, i.e. that there would exist an according polyhedron with such indivdual values. It just tells the opposite: outside of these ranges there cannot be found any (convex) polyhedron with such values.

--- rk